# How to ask person A and send the result to person B after consulting with Person A?

Tags: grammaticality

How to ask person A and send the result to person B after consulting with Person A?

I would like to tell to person A:

> I will consult with person B and send to you the result for references.

Is my sentences correct?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm totally clueless what exactly you want to convey, considering that the title and the drafted sentence don't mean the same, at least to me. Let's say, if you are C, could you make it clear who consults who? and who will send the result(s) to who?

Comment: Did you mix up Person A with Person B?  The question title suggests you'll consult with A and send the results to B, but the question body suggests you'll consult with B and send the results to A.  Which did you mean to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is understandable to a native speaker.  However, "send you the result for references" is a little confusing.

As a native speaker I would say something like this:

> I will consult with Person B and then **get back to you**.